# Angular 7 retaining the Original list in the @Input property

Tags: angular

I have implemented a checkbox and capturing its event via a service. I am basically trying to filter the array based on the checkbox selection and filtering the array.  In the component code I have currently two properties. If you see below I binding the dropdown list to 
LegalFundClasses property which reads the value from FundClasses property which is an Input property. The first time when the form loads i can see the unfiltered list. The moment the checkbox is true, the list gets filtered but I am loosing the original filtered list. I have shared the component code
where i am doing the filtering. How do I maintain the original list

Component

```
    public get FundClasses(): any {
        return this._fundClasses;
    }
    @Input()
    public set FundClasses(value: any) {
        this._fundClasses = value;
    }

    get LegalFundClasses(): any {
        if (this.FundClasses) {
        return this.FundClasses.LegalFundClasses;
        }
    }

    set LegalFundClasses(value: any) {
        this.FundClasses.LegalFundClasses = value;
    }

  openFundClassModal() {
        if (this.addFundClassComponent != null) {
            this.fundClassWindowOpened = true;
            if (this.termsStateService.IsInvested) {
                this.LegalFundClasses = this.LegalFundClasses.filter(x=> x.InvestedStatusId !== 0);
            } 
        }
    }
```

html

```
<kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [data]="LegalFundClasses" [(ngModel)]="FundClass"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" 
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="false" valueField="Id">
 </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: are you sure about getting LegalFundClasses from this.FundClasses. Because you are setting the input to  this._fundClasses. Is this a typo

Comment: hari  I didnt understand your confusion. The FundClasses is an input element and gets set by its parent. The LegalFundClasses has a get that reads from FundClasses  which is already set by its parent component.

Comment: Tom, I understand, I will suggest an edit in the answer section please try it out

Comment: why dont you simply add a new class member `filteredList` that is set whenever the filter options or the source list change?

Comment: Hi jota can you please show me an example

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
@Input()
    public set FundClasses(value: any) {
        this._fundClasses = value;
    }
```

to

```
 @Input() FundClasses: any
```

Because set prefix means any changes to the input variable from the parent component will be set as and when changes occur, and might be changing your list items. Without it, FundClasses will be set only once. Also please try not to assign filtered values to the variable again

Comment: If I dont set the LegalFundClasses property how will i  show the filtered list

Comment: Also another thing to note is that FundClasses array would increase over time so the component should know when new elements are added

Comment: Tom, in that case please ignore the changes I mentioned. But still you are trying to get LegalFundClasses from FundClasses variable which is not preferable. Instead please try to retrieve it from this._fundClasses

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to keep two separate list to achieve what you want. 
when you set LegalFundClasses it also set the original list.

```
@Input('FundClasses') fundClasses: any; // original data
legalFundClasses: any; // use it filtered data to show.
  openFundClassModal() {
        if (this.addFundClassComponent != null) {
            this.fundClassWindowOpened = true;
            if (this.termsStateService.IsInvested) {
                this.legalFundClasses = this.fundClasses.filter(x=> x.InvestedStatusId !== 0);
            } 
        }
    }
```